# Firebase Authentication using custom fields

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-authentication, customization

I have been using firebase authentication process using email and password. This is working perfectly fine. But i want to add the username while creating the account. But using this auth function i could send only two params like,

`const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(name.value, email.value, password.value);`

The workaround suggested to me is getting the username after creating the username. But i want the data to sent along with email while creating the account. Is there a way i could send the user name along with this create user request, so that i could get the username whenever i log in. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass an email and a password to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, so you can't set a name using this function.

If you want to set a name for the authenticated user, you need to use the `updateProfile()` method on the user object, like this:

```js
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jon Snow"
})
```

Note that the property is called `displayName`, not `name`.

You can set the name right after creating the user. This example uses async/await:

```js
const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email,
  password
)

await user.updateProfile({ displayName: name });
```

Or, using promises:

```js
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(({ user }) => user.updateProfile({ displayName: name }))
  .then(() => {
    console.log("User was updated!", auth.currentUser.displayName);
  });
```

If you need the user object somewhere else in your code, you can call `firebase.auth().currentUser`, or [attach a listener to the authentication object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).

You can only set a limited number of properties on Firebase users (like `displayName`, `email` and `photoURL`). Additional (custom) data must be stored somewhere else, e.g. in Firestore, together with the user's uid.